# Issue installing R package from github using devtools

Tags: r, devtools

In similar fashion to the following question:

[Error when using install_github: 'exdir' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829100/error-when-using-install-github-exdir-does-not-exist?rq=1)

I cant seem to install packages from github using the `devtools` package, getting the following error on all packages I've tried (slidify, rCharts, rga, magrittr etc...):

```
Error in unzip(src, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file 'C:/Users/.../Rtemp\RtmpGIlGBA/master.zip' cannot be opened
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unzip(src, exdir = target, unzip = getOption("unzip")) :
    error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

I've changed the temporary directory to somewhere writeable in case this was the problem:

```
    write("TMP = 'C:/Users/.../Rtemp' \n
           TMPDIR = 'C:/Users/.../Rtemp' \n
           TEMP = 'C:/Users/.../Rtemp'", 
            append = TRUE,
            file = file.path(Sys.getenv('R_USER'), '.Renviron'))
    readRenviron(".Renviron")
```

But to no avail. I have also `setwd()` to somewhere else and checked whether there is an issue with `unzip()` by getting the zip file from github directly:

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://github.com/ramnathv/slidifyLibraries/archive/master.zip",temp)
unzip(temp)
```

This appears to work fine, and I've since installed the packages using `build()` etc... but it is **not** as handy as the `install_github()`. Any ideas?

Here is my `sessionInfo()` :

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.5 httr_0.3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4   evaluate_0.5.5 memoise_0.2.1  parallel_3.1.1 RCurl_1.95-4.2 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.1    whisker_0.3-2 
Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/archive/master.zip)
```

Comment: Run R as an administrator.

Comment: R is run as administrator obviously. Breaking up the install into two steps works without a hitch: `download.file(url, 'master.zip')` followed by `install_local('master.zip')`, so I'm guessing its something in `install_github()`???