# Unable to run packages from GitHub in R using devtools

Tags: r, github, package, devtools, installation-package

Every time I try to download a package from GitHub using [devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools) I get an error. I'm currently trying to open the `elan` package:

```
 library(devtools)
 devtools::install_github("dalejbarr/elan")
```

I get the following error:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Daniel &
>   Catherine/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’  (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) 
>   Error: no packages specified  The system cannot find the path
>   specified.  Error: Failed to install 'elan' from GitHub:    (converted
>   from warning) installation of package
>   ‘C:/rtemp/Rtmp0gabkG/file5580567f6ac9/elan_0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero
>   exit status

I've tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035307/issue-installing-r-package-from-github-using-devtools) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744865/unable-to-install-github-packages-in-r), but neither fix the problem. I understand that there might be a problem with the spaces in the path name, but there's not much I can do about that (I don't want to set up a new user on my computer just to run [devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools)).

My `SessionInfo()` is:

```
 R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
 Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
 Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

 Matrix products: default

 locale:
 [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                                 LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] devtools_2.2.2 usethis_1.5.1 

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] Rcpp_1.0.2        rstudioapi_0.10   magrittr_1.5      pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.4.0          rlang_0.4.0       tools_3.6.1       pkgbuild_1.0.3         sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_1.1.0         withr_2.1.2       ellipsis_0.3.0   
 [13] remotes_2.1.1     assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.21     rprojroot_1.3-2   crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.4.0    callr_3.3.0       fs_1.3.1          ps_1.3.0          curl_3.3          testthat_2.2.1    memoise_1.1.0    
 [25] glue_1.3.1        compiler_3.6.1    desc_1.2.0        backports_1.1.5   prettyunits_1.0.2
```

Comment: Workaround: Download the zipfile and install in via `install.packages("pathtoZIPfile.zip", repos=NULL)`. I think the main problem really is the username

Comment: That gives me the message `Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Daniel & Catherine/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)`, and then when I try to run the package with `library()` it says there is no package called elan.

Comment: Please also add your `sessionInfo()`, it fails to install for me (R version 3.6.2), too, looks like my dplyr version is too old. `"package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3"`

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/spaces-in-library-path-names-on-windows-causes-problems-installing-packages-after-installing-r-3-5-0/8978/4 Install the packages and R in C:/R

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code at https://github.com/dalejbarr/elan/blob/master/DESCRIPTION I found a potential error of format. You could try to clone the repository and debug it manually by removing the extra spaces in front on the `XML` package import :

**DESCRIPTION file**

```
Package: elan
Title: Read ELAN XML files
Version: 0.1
Authors@R: "Dale Barr <dalejbarr3@gmail.com> [aut, cre]"
Description: Read ELAN XML files to tidy output
Depends:
    R (>= 3.1.1),
    dplyr
Imports:
      XML,
    plyr
License: 
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.0.2
```

I tried it in a minimal package and this raise a problem (but the package still compiles without the scripts).

Alternatively you could use the `XML`(which this small package uses) or the `xml2` (as [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2015/04/21/xml2/)) package to parse your XML files.

Comment: I can run the cloned script this way, but when I try to actually use the elan package it won't work. I think the problem has more to do with `devtools` than this package specifically.

Comment: This is not obvious : `devtools` is a robust well established package and this package seems nice but it is a small 2015 github contribution (no CRAN) and there is at least a problem in the source. Thus, if it is was me, I would look for problem into to the `elan` package or use `xml2` instead.