# Rcmd check/Rcmd build leads with file not found, leading devtools::check to fail package installation

Tags: r

**The issue:**

On one PC, Rcmd check/Rcmd build always lead with *The system cannot find the path specified*, and has an exit code of 1. They otherwise operate properly. However, this causes devtools::check and remotes::install_local to fail, leaving me unable to install packages from source properly and causes issues with package deployment scripts I'm using.

Even when running `Rcmd check --help` or `Rcmd build --help`, before the normal help file, I get the message *The system cannot find the path specified* and the exit code is 1.

**What have I tried:**

- A full reinstall of R.
- Using a different version of R.
- Deleting HKCU\Software\R-core and HKLM\Software\R-core from the registry (I've noted that R can run properly without these, they just help RStudio/others help find R).
- Setting R_LIBS_USER in the system environment, and removing it.

**What have I found online:**

- [This post on RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/build-package-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/76435) may have the same issue, but is closed without a reply.
- [This post on RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-resolve-install-github-fails-with-error-system-command-rcmd-exe-failed-exit-status-1-stdout-stderr/95202) reports on two people that may have the same issue. One of them hasn't solved it, the other has performed a full Windows reinstallation (which worked, but which I *really* don't want to do).
- [Unable to run packages from GitHub in R using devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722690) appears to have a different issue, I don't get  *Error: no packages specified* when trying to install anything.

I know this isn't a usual question, as I can't provide a reproducible example. I'm happy to provide any information requested (don't think `version`/`Sys.info()`/`sessioninfo()` provide help since this occurs with multiple R versions, and without starting R at all by just using `Rcmd` (but in devtools too of course)). Any suggestions are very much welcome.

Comment: It should be `Rcmd check`:  `check` is lowercase.  But I think the error happens with `Rcmd`, not with `check`.  Is it on your path?

Comment: @user2554330 Regarding the lower case, sorry, I'm actually using lowercase but somehow mistyped that in my question. Regarding the error being with Rcmd, I don't think so, Rcmd BATCH works fine. Rcmd is on my path. Also, remember that besides closing with an error code and outputting _The system cannot find the path specified_ as the first line, Rcmd build appears to be working just fine, but devtools/remotes of course error on the nonzero exit code

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  It might be that it is trying to look at a library that doesn't exist or gives permission errors.  Maybe you can put together a script that will print some more diagnostics, and run it with `Rcmd BATCH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

An old miniconda install, installed a long time ago through reticulate, somehow got deleted without cleaning up the relevant registry keys.

An incorrect value in the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun` caused this behavior. It automatically starts scripts whenever `cmd.exe` starts. It pointed to a deleted conda script.

Deleting this registry key solved the issue.