# Sorting data by type in R

Tags: r, sorting, types

I am struggling to write a function for a dataset that looks like this:

```
identifier   age   occupation        
pers1        18    student   
pers2        45    teacher   
pers3        65    retired
```

What I am trying to do, is to write a function that will:

1. sort my variables into numerical vs. factor variable
2. for the numerical variables, give me the mean, min and mx
3. for the factor variable, give me a frequency table
4. return point (2) and (3) in a "nice" format (dataframe, vector or table)

So far, I have tried this:

```
describe<- function(x) 
{ if (is.numeric(x)) { mean <- mean(x)
                   min <- min(x)
                   max <- max(x) 
                   d <- data.frame(mean, min, max)}
  else { factor <- table(x) }
}
stats <- lapply(data, describe)
```

Problems:
My problem is that now, "stats" is a list that is difficult to read and to export to Excel or share. I don't know how to make the list "stats" more reader-friendly.

Alternatively, maybe is there a better way to build the function "describe"?

Any thoughts on how to solve these two problems are much appreciated!

Comment: What do you think of `summary(data)[c(1,4,6),]`   ?

Comment: Try `sapply` instead. See its help page, argument `simplify`.

Comment: @G5W - Thanks! That works, it's just that the dataset has 168 variables, so it's a bit lengthy to do "by hand". :)

Comment: @RuiBarradas - Thanks! Will give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ma be late to the party, but maybe you still need a solution. I combined the answers from some of the comments to your post to the following code. It assumes you only have numerical columns and factors, and scales to a large number of columns, as you specified:

```
# Just some sample data for my example, you don't need ggplot2.
library(ggplot2)
data=diamonds

# Find which columns are numeric, and which are not.
classes = sapply(data,class)
numeric = which(classes=="numeric")
non_numeric = which(classes!="numeric")

# create the summary objects    
summ_numeric = summary(data[,numeric])
summ_non_numeric = summary(data[,non_numeric])

# result is easily written to csv
write.csv(summ_non_numeric,file="test.csv")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is great & it works & it's the closest to what I had in mind.

Comment: Happy to know that it was helpful to you, thanks for sharing your progress!

Answer (score 1):

The desired functionality is already available elsewhere, so if you are not interested in coding it yourself then you can maybe use this. The `Publish` package can be used to generate a table for presentation in a paper. It is not on CRAN, but you can install it from github

```
devtools::install_github('tagteam/Publish')
library(Publish)
library(isdals)  # Get some data
data(fev)        
fev$Smoke <- factor(fev$Smoke, levels=0:1, labels=c("No", "Yes"))
fev$Gender <- factor(fev$Gender, levels=0:1, labels=c("Girl", "Boy"))
```

The `univariateTable` can generate a publication-ready table presenting the data. By default, `univariateTable` computes the mean and standard deviation for numeric variables and the distribution of observations in categories for factors. These values can be computed and compared across groups.   The main input to `univariateTable` is a formula where the right-hand side lists the variables to be included in the table while the left-hand side --- if present --- specifies a grouping variable.

```
univariateTable(Smoke ~ Age + Ht + FEV + Gender, data=fev)
```

This produces the following output

```
  Variable     Level No (n=589) Yes (n=65) Total (n=654) p-value
1      Age mean (sd)  9.5 (2.7) 13.5 (2.3)     9.9 (3.0)  <1e-04
2       Ht mean (sd) 60.6 (5.7) 66.0 (3.2)    61.1 (5.7)  <1e-04
3      FEV mean (sd)  2.6 (0.9)  3.3 (0.7)     2.6 (0.9)  <1e-04
4   Gender      Girl 279 (47.4)  39 (60.0)    318 (48.6)        
5                Boy 310 (52.6)  26 (40.0)    336 (51.4)  0.0714
```

Comment: Sounds like a great package. But, I can´t install it, I get the following errors:                                                                                         
    > library(devtools)
    Warning message:
    package ‘devtools’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
    > devtools::install_github('tagteam/Publish')
     Downloading GitHub repo tagteam/Publish@master
    from URL https://api.github.com/repos/tagteam/Publish/zipball/master
    Installation failed: 'exdir' does not exist
    > library(Publish)
    Error in library(Publish) : there is no package called ‘Publish’

Comment: Ah. Maybe time to ping the author (which isn't me) and raise an issue.

Comment: Oh. Are you using R 3.4? Maybe time to update your devtools package

Comment: Updated all packages. Still not working... :) I really appreciate the help, though.

Comment: Maybe it's a write permission. See [this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829100/error-when-using-install-github-exdir-does-not-exist)